# Word 2010 using Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word-2010

I just purchased an HP All-in-one desktop with Windows 8 and installed Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010.  It was working perfectly for about a week.

Now when I open Word to create a document, I get this message: "Word could not create the work file.  Check the temp environment variable".  When I clicked on Help to try and debug this problem, I got the message: "There is a problem with one or more installed help files.  Please repair your Office installation and try again".

I tried uninstalling Microsoft Office, but couldn't.

Comment: What happened when you try to uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

Micorosft support article that could solve your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2285187

Comment: How about a bit more detail and not just a link (that could have been posted as a comment)?